# Sort by date translations?

Tags: translation, time

I am translating my diary app to Chinese.

In my app, there's a search feature that searches for the user's diaries. The user can adjust some search options. one of the options is how the search results should be sorted. The user can choose

- Earlier → Later
- Later → Earlier

If Earlier -> Later is selected, June 25 will be ordered before June 26, and vice versa.

I am kind of stuck on how to translate these two choices, even though I am a native speaker...

I tried

- 更早 → 更晚 but the 更 seems weird. If I remove it,
- 早 → 晚 it sounds like morning to night
- 时间升序排列 it sounds a little technical. And since most people don't have a concept of "a later date is a bigger date", it won't make too much sense to people
- 较早 → 较晚 this is fine at first but then I thought that users might think that it does not show *very* early results. You know, it's only *较*早.

So what can I translate this into so that people won't misunderstand it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider:

- Earlier → Later: 由舊到新 (From old to new)
- Later → Earlier: 由新到舊 (From new to old)

Real life example:

This wording has been used by YouTube for users to select the sorting order of comments under each video.

Comment: That's a good idea!

Answer (score 1):

What about 按日期顺序 and 按日期倒序?
These are the ones I usually see.

Comment: This is a good idea. But I think it's a little bit too formal than the answer by wilson. I want to use a more colloquial word.

Answer (score 0):

In most of Chinese websites, “更早” and “更晚” are used to page forward and page backward.

It's much appropriate to use word “最”, “最” implies “most”. Personally, I'm prefer to use phrases “最新日记” (latest diary) and “最早日记” (earliest diary), they are presented in nature language, thus easier to read and to understand.

Comment: I was also going to suggest 最.